# Cannot push to gerrit as the previous changeset was abandoned

Tags: git, gerrit

The past 3 commits in my local working tree are as follows:

```
latest: my current changes
latest-1: my previous commit, that I pushed to gerrit and subsequently aborted
latest-2: an earlier commit by someone else
```

Now when I get error as follows:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev (change https://git/1326970 closed)
```

`1326970` is the changeset for the `latest-1` commit that I abandoned. How do I remove it from my local workingtree as well?

When I do `git remote update && git rebase` git says `First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...` and the it applies the two commits `LATEST-1` and `LATEST`. Do I need to reset back to before that and then make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to get rid of commits, use `git reset`. In this case, if you want to keep your `latest` commit but remove `latest-1`, it's a little more complicated because you can't just set your branch back X commits.

Remember that Git's data structures have each commit pointing to its parent commit(s), so `latest` contains a reference to `latest-1`. What we need to do is synthesize a new `latest` commit that no longer includes the stuff you changed in `latest-1`, and stores `latest-2` as its parent.

That sounds complicated but fortunately Git has a powertool to do history mangling, called *interactive rebase*, goes like this:

1. You run `git rebase -i latest-2` ("do horrible things to everything after `latest-2`").
2. Git launches an editor that lists your commits. Delete lines to remove the commits, plus there are a bunch of other things you can do, documented in the manpage for `git rebase`, section *Interactive Mode*.
3. Once you're done, save and quit and Git will re-generate commits based on what you've ordered. (If you changed your mind, clear the editor content before saving and it will abort.)

   - During each commit being re-generated (`latest`, in your case), conflicts may occur (if the changes in `latest` "depend on" the changes in `latest-1`). Git will add conflict markers to the file(s) and tell you how to proceed.

Be careful with doing this on merge commits. By default, interactive rebase mangles them terribly. You can tell it not to do that using the `-p` option, but you get entirely different code paths and there may be subtle other differences.

---

Alternatively, here's a quicker option for this particular case: reset and then manually re-apply individual commits.

```
git reset --hard latest-2 # warning, destroys uncommitted changes
git cherry-pick latest # ID of latest (which is now gone but can still be referenced)
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand the first option you described, probably because the second seems simpler. The `latest` commit is actually quite small so I don't need to cherry pick but the rest part is what I needed. Thanks.